# ubuntu/WSL1: ip command not working

Tags: networking, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to debug the networking setup in ubuntu/WSL1. For some reason, I cannot add or delete routes:

```
# ip addr add 2a01:4f8:131:5085::2/64 dev eth0
RTNETLINK answers: Permission denied
```

What can cause this error?

Comment: You need to run bash on windows as an administrator

Comment: @Ramhound I am running the command as root in Ubuntu. You're saying I can install bash on windows? But then how would it affect WSL, if it's not running in WSL?

Comment: I didn't ask if you are running the command as sudo, actually, I didn't ask anything, I said you need to run Bash on Windows as an Administrator.  In other words, when you launch Ubuntu WSL, run it as an Administrator

Comment: @Ramhound Tried that, got `RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Ramhound In any case, I am asking how to change the networking in ubuntu/WSL1. Not to change the networking in Windows. The networking is working just fine in Windows and I don't want to change it.

Comment: I am not suggesting you change the networking on Windows.  The fact you got a different error, suggest, this is a permission problem.

Comment: You can try `sudo ifconfig eth0 up`, but otherwise, this error can be ignored, since it likely has to do with IPv6 .  I assume even though you have an error everything else works?

Comment: @personal_cloud Under WSL1, the WSL network *is* the Windows network.  WSL2, on the other hand, uses a virtual network that is separate from Windows.  In WSL1, there's really no way to change the network without changing the Windows side as well, and for that reason, I don't think most "write/edit" syscalls are implemented in the WSL1 translation layer for networking.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds This seems to be the answer. So it indeed turns out that my Ubuntu and Windows networks are behaving identically. (my issue was actually just DNS configuration). Thank you for explaining it to me.